# An unhandled exception is occured The application will be restarted

Tags: ubuntu

> «An unhandled exception is occured The application will be restarted»

Что сделать? Ппользуюсь ubuntu первый день.

Answer (score 1):

В данной ошибке говориться, что приложение будет закрыто по непонятным соображениям.

Тут может быть все что угодно: бэд на винте, битая оператива и т.п.

Также можно покопаться в лог файлах системы и найти более подробный лог ошибки, тогда можно будет понять точнее.